# Error handling of returning values from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, error-handling, return-value

Using C++ I'm working on a method in DLL which returns a value of temperature from a device.

I would like to return as well an error status of the device in case if temperature can not be read. This way I want to add kind of error handling to avoid calling extra methods to get device status.

So I can not return a wrong temperature value if it can not be properly read, e.g. if device is not initialized I could return -1.0  or -2.0 but it can be interpreted as the temperature.

Also I want that calling of this method and using this DLL will be compatible with another programming languages such as Pascal/Delphi, Python etc.

in Java I would make a jar with the such method:

```
public float getTemperature() throws Exception{

 float temperature;

 try{
   
   temperature = ...;

   return temperature;

 }catch(Exception E){

    throw new Exception("Device not initialized...")

 }      

}
```

would it be correct to implement this in C++ the following way where temperature will be returned by parameter and the negative return values of method contain error codes:

declaration:

```
extern "C" MYDLL int getTemperature(float*);
```

implementation:

```
int getTemperature(float* temp)
{

  if (device_not_ready)
  {
    *temp = 0;
    return -1;
  }

  if (device_has_error) 
  {
    *temp = 0;
    return -2;

  }

  float temperature = device_temperature;
    
  *temp = temperature;

  return 1;

}
```

Comment: you should use references instead of pointers for parameters when a `nullptr` is not a valid input. Otherwise, the code looks ok, do you see any problem?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have with the code you show? Are you just asking if that way is okay (for which the answer is, "it's okay") or not?

Comment: Thank you for the notes, I've modified the text to highlight the problem.

Comment: You have many, many ways you could use to signal an error. You can throw an exception, you could return a `struct` with the temperature and an error code, you could return a `std::optional` that either holds a temperature or not and not holding one means error. You could pass in a reference to a variable you write an error code to if something fails. And more. You just have to make up your mind as to how you want to do it / what fits best with the existing code in the project.

Comment: I can not use struct or throw an exception as DLL can be used in Delphi, Python, JNI etc...

Comment: your approach is perfectly valid. but in the case of error, I would not modify the temp ( for ex. set it to 0). The client of getTemperature() should decide what to do in this case.

Comment: StPiere - thank you for the feedback as from client's point of view.